# How to fetch network data directly when app is started?

Tags: asynchronous, networking, dart, flutter

I'm implementing Youtube Clone App using Bloc pattern. For now, I'm fetching thumbnail image of videos and creating a ListView by that image.

I want to load directly 3 images from internet when app is started, but It is not working when I wrote that code in `initState()` function.

```
      @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _getVideo();
      _getVideo();  
      _getVideo();
      _scrollController.addListener((){
        if(_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent){
          _getVideo();
        }
      });
    }

  @override
    void dispose() {
      _scrollController.dispose();
      _youtubeBloc.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

  Future<void> _getVideo() async {
    VideoModel model = await _youtubeApi.getChannelVideo(index);
    _youtubeBloc.addChannelData(model);
    index++;
  }
```

In `initState()` function, I call `_getVideo()` method for three times, but It cannot fetch data from internet, so my question is that how can I fetch data from network directly when app is started?

Comment: There is no stacktrace, it doesn't show anything

Comment: When I open the app, it waits for some time and shut down...

Comment: `Exited (sigterm)` just this

Comment: Please post a complete runnable reproduction incl `main() {}` so that it's possible to investigate.

Comment: I added more codes

Comment: For minimal reproduction you should remove all code that is not related to the problem. For example `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` is completely unrelated. This makes it only harder to figure out what the problem is about and how to fix or work around.

Comment: What is `youtube_clone`. This prevents others to run the code. I don't see anything wrong in your code. It's probably one of the used plugins that crash the app.

Comment: I edited, what I'm curious is that how can I load videos when app is started like original Youtube app?

Comment: I solved, it was due to index handling, sorry for bothering.